# Show another view on login success angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, location

Today I started working on angular.js conversion of a website. I have an `index.html` which serves as the main page within which I have `ng-view` for my other views. I have created `login` and `signup` view so far. I am collaborating with a backend developer who has advised me to use rest client to work with the data he has added as json. All that works fine. Now I am stuck with a condition where I need to [authenticate the login page], not sure if can call it that way. If the login is success I want the dashboard view to appear. I just want to know how to do this just using "front-end", as this is just for the time being to test the app with.
Here is the code.
**app.js**

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name servicepriceApp
 * @description
 * # servicepriceApp
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */
var myApp;
(function() {
    myApp = angular
        .module('servicepriceApp', [
            'ngRoute'
        ])
        .config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/signup', {
                    templateUrl: 'views/signup.html',
                    controller: 'SignupController'
                })

            .when('/login', {
                    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
                    controller: 'LoginController'
                })
                .when('/dashboard', {
                    templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
                    controller: 'DashController'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: 'views/signup.html'
                });
        });
})();
```

**login.js**

```
myApp.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.login = function() {

        var data = {
            email: $scope.email,
            password: $scope.password
        };
        $http({
            url: site + '/company/login',
            method: "POST",
            transformRequest: encodeurl,
            data: data,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function(res) {

            console.log(res);

        });
    }
});
```

**index.html**

```
  <!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" ng-app="servicepriceApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Service price</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/foundation.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#signup"> SignUp </a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#login"> Login </a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#dashboard"> Dashboard </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/signup.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/login.js"></script>

    <!-- endbuild -->
</body>

</html>
```

**signup.html**

```
var site = "http://someurl.in:9009"
var encodeurl = function(obj) {
    var str = [];
    for (var p in obj)
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
    return str.join("&");
}
myApp.controller('SignupController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.signup = function() {

        var data = {
            email: $scope.email,
            password: $scope.password
        };
        $http({
            url: site + '/company/signup',
            method: "POST",
            transformRequest: encodeurl,
            data: data,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);

        }).error(function(res) {

            console.log(res);

        });
    }
});
```

I hope this much code is enough for you to have an idea how this is going on. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I used `.success(function(data) {
            console.dir(data);
            if (data.login === "ok") {
                $location.path("/dashboard");
            }` and it works for me. However, I get an error when I reach dashboard page. Can anyone guide me to a beginner tutorial which use $location to change view. Will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The above code fixed my issue. The bug was due to the wrong controller usage. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    For changing the view you need to add just $location.path("/dashboard");
    Like:-


    $http({
                    url: site + '/company/signup',
                    method: "POST",
                    transformRequest: encodeurl,
                    data: data,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    }
                }).success(function(data) {
$location.path("/dashboard"); //this line is required for dashboard.
                    console.log(data);

                }).error(function(res) {

                    console.log(res);

                });
```

Comment: Won't this change the view from signup to dashboard on successful signup? I wan't the view to appear on successful login. So I should replace the same for `login.js` right?